# Cakephp and Server Side Events

Tags: cakephp, events

I've configured cakephp 2.6.3 with the events system. 
Post data comes in via a controller method and is handled. This data is then passed to an event file as per their [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/events.html)

The listener is registering the event as I can write to the log from it. I have a server sent event setup, and I want to pass the resulting data from the listener to this controller method so it can be sent as an event. How do I do this?

Post Data 'Mocked' up event for testing in DataController: - I call this method via a URL to fire the event

```
public function test_event() {

    $data = array(
        'lat' => 'lattitude',
        'lng' => 'longigiggi',
        'msg' => 'my message here'
    );
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->layout = false;
    $event = new CakeEvent('Data.post.received', $this, array('data', $data));
    $this->getEventManager()->dispatch($event);

}
```

Here is my Event Listener in Lib/Event/TradeData

```
public function implementedEvents() {
    return array(
        'Data.post.received' => 'fireThis',
    );
}

public function fireThis($event){
    CakeLog::write('debug', 'Event listener fired');

    //how do I pass data from the event here to a controller method
    // to propogate a server sent event in DataController->test_listener();
    // The event is being triggered, as its writing to the log
}
```

DataController::test_listener();

```
public function test_listener($data = null) {

    $trade = new EventController();
    $this->getEventManager()->attach($trade);

    $this->layout = false;

    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

    $lat = $data['lat'];
    $lng = $data['lng'];
    $msg = $data['msg'];

    $this->set(compact('lat', 'lng', 'msg'));
    $this->render('/Elements/sse');


}
```

The view `Elements/sse` is configured correctly for Server Sent Events

```
<?php
echo "data: {\n";
echo "data: \"lat\": \"$lat\",\n";
echo "data: \"lng\": \"$lng\",\n";
echo "data: \"country\": \"$msg\"\n";
echo "data: }\n\n";
flush();
```

How do I  render data to the same page that the server sent event will be listening to?

Comment: Can u tell, what url to use on client side to connect to event stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your Listener and raiser need to be attached somewhere other than in a controller method that you're going to call from the Listener. Maybe you already did this, but in your bootstrap.php file you should have something like:

```
// Load event listeners
App::uses('TradeData', 'Lib/Event');
App::uses('CakeEventManager', 'Event');

// Attach listeners.
CakeEventManager::instance()->attach(new TradeData());
```

Then, in the TradeData Listener you can call the controller (subject) method in the fireThis() function:

```
$event->subject->test_listener($event->data);
```

Also, you can simplify the data being passed to CakeEvent so it would look like this:

```
$event = new CakeEvent('Data.post.received', $this, $data);
```